# ADT Bundle for Mac: Eclipse cannot be started

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, installation, adt

I downloaded Android Developer Tools Bundle for Mac from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). The System Requirements section says it needs "Mac OS X 10.5.8 or later (**x86** only)". I tried to start Eclipse.app in adt-bundle-mac-**x86_64**/eclipse, but I got the following error message:

> You can't open the application Eclipse.app because it is not supported
>   on this type of Mac.

I have a Macbook with **32-bit** Intel Core Duo CPU and Mac OS X 10.6.8 and JRE 1.6.0_39. Why can't I start Eclipse from the ADT bundle? If I install Eclipse Classic 4.2.1 32-bit from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-421/junosr1), it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

> I have a Macbook with 32-bit

and this:

> I tried to start Eclipse.app in adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/eclipse

do not line up. It would appear that you are trying to use a 64-bit Eclipse on a 32-bit environment, based on your description.

There does not appear to be a 32-bit OS X version of the ADT bundle, so you may need to install the SDK Tools and Eclipse separately rather than use the bundle.

Comment: @kol: On Windows and Linux, `x86_64` means it works only on 64-bit systems. Conversely, 32-bit tools can usually work on 64-bit Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download

Go there and make sure you choose 32 bit for the download. That should resolve your issue.

Comment: Hmm, interesting: The platform for adt-bundle-mac-x86_64.zip is Mac OS X 64-bit, so it seems there is no 32-bit Mac version :(

Comment: Yep sorry. It looks like you are correct. You can still download Eclipse and then add ADT manually though. All is not lost! :)